# How to make yAxis stackLabels under yAxis in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am using **[Stacked and grouped column](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped)** to display data, I want to show the **yAxis stackLabels** and let it below **yAxis** as the picture shown below:
[image: show stacklabels under yaxis]

below is my core code and I have created a **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpd2xxr9/)** to show the result:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
            offset:30
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            //offset:10,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                //y:30, //it will won't display labels if y is greater than 0
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'gray'
                },
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.stack;
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                     'Stack: ' + this.series.options.stack;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
            stack: 'female'
        }, {
            name: 'Janet',
            data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
            stack: 'female'
        }]
    });
});
```

I found that if I set the value of **y** greater than 0 it will not show the stacklabels.

Can anyone help me, thanks a lot!

```js
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    y:30, //it will won't display labels if y is greater than 0
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'gray'
    },
    formatter: function() {
        return this.stack;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use CSS (see https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css):

```
.highcharts-stack-labels text {
  transform: translate(0, 20px);
}
```

Your fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/jraw54c2/

Answer (score 1):

By default It is as you say

> I found that if I set the value of y greater than 0,it will not show the stacklabels

To have desired  behavior, you have to do following things:

1>Add  extra series with negative values in  each stack.

```
    series: [{
      name: 'test',
      data: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      stack: 'male',
      color: 'transparent', //transparent color 
      showInLegend: false,  //hide legend
    }, {
      name: 'tests',
      data: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      stack: 'female',
      color: 'transparent',
      showInLegend: false,
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
      stack: 'male'
    }, {
      name: 'Joe',
      data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
      stack: 'male'
    }, {
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
      stack: 'female'
    }, {
      name: 'Janet',
      data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
      stack: 'female'
    }]
```

2> In `stackLabel` property of `yAxis` you have to hide positive value stack labels

```
   formatter: function() {
      if (this.isNegative) {
        return this.stack;
      }
   }
```

3>`yAxis` values should start from 0 show hide negative values,

```
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          console.log(this.value)
          if (this.value > -1) {
            return this.value
          }

        }
      },
```

4>Similarly tooltip should not activate on negative values

```
 tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.y > -1) {
          return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
            this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
            'Stack: ' + this.series.options.stack;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

      }
    },
```

Applying this output

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
      //offset:30
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      //offset:10,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.value > -1) {
            return this.value
          }

        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Number of fruits'
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 0,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'gray'
        },
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.isNegative) {
            return this.stack;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.y > -1) {
          return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
            this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
            'Stack: ' + this.series.options.stack;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'test',
      data: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      stack: 'male',
      color: 'transparent',
      showInLegend: false,
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: ''
      }
    }, {
      name: 'tests',
      data: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      stack: 'female',
      color: 'transparent',
      showInLegend: false,
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: ''
      }
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
      stack: 'male'
    }, {
      name: 'Joe',
      data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
      stack: 'male'
    }, {
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
      stack: 'female'
    }, {
      name: 'Janet',
      data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
      stack: 'female'
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: To Deep 3015,thank you for your reply,but I found beaver's answer is more simple and elegant,I accepted his answer and up vote yours,thank you very much!

Comment: ya I agree _beaver's answer is more simple and elegant_

Comment: but be cautious if there is multiple charts in same page. it will effect globally.